# Dismiss Android push Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, push, dismiss

Some question about push notifications. How do I dissmis all the notifications of my app when I press one of them? Also ... how do I dissmiss the noifications if I start the app (not from the noification)?

Here is how I send a notification from my GcmIntentService class (if it is helpfull).

```
private void sendNotification(Bundle extras) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NOTIFICATION_ID = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("id"));

    Intent in = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
    in.putExtras(extras);
    in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    String msg = extras.getString("msj");

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("MY TITLE")
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: try `mBuilder.cancelAll()`

Comment: mBuiler does no allow me to do .cancelAll(); Any idea?

Comment: why? go to official [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: Ok so this accepts cancelAll(): mNotificationManager.cancelAll(); But where should I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the notifications you are putting out are for the same event, if so you can do what is called "stacking notifications" like Gmail does when you get a second or third email. It's all in the one notification and therefore will go away as one. This is only compatible above 4.1.

This is the code Google gives along with the stacking. This any help?

```
mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setContentTitle("New Message")
.setContentText("You've received new messages.")
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
...
mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
    .setNumber(++numMessages);
// Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
// updated.
mNotificationManager.notify(
        notifyID,
        mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I don't need to show all the otification as a single one. It would be easy to dismiss that one noification with .setAutoCancel(true). Any idea of how can I dissmiss all of them? And how do dismiss all of them also when I start the app?

Comment: OK so i took a look at this, is not a bad idea. The problem is that it is only compatible above 4.1 =(

Comment: Ok there is the CancelAll() which will cancel all previous notifications. This can be called when clicking on a notification and then you could also add it when you start up your program. Here's a link for more info on managing your notifications. [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancelAll())

Answer (score 0):

try `android.app.NotificationManager.cancelAll()`